# How can I send a dynamic message to the user with an existing HTML page and without alert box?

Tags: java, html, servlets

I am trying to relay a response as my servlet authorization completes. This message contains (good afternoon,night"username"). I managed to get this working with the following

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Tijd + naam , "Verbonden!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

But somehow this doesnt work when i deployed it in tomcat. So I am trying to figure out how im able to display a message to the user (which changes dynamically based on the time which i already got working). And preferably show this message injected into the already existing landing page where the response redirect is sent to.

Is this possible?

```
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = cal.get( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY );
    String Tijd ="";

    if( hour > 5 && hour < 12 )
        Tijd = ( "Goede morgen, " );
    else if( hour < 18 )
       Tijd = ( "Goede Middag, " );
    else if( hour < 00 )
      Tijd = ( "Goede avond, " );
    else
        Tijd = ( "Good night, " );

    naam = request.getParameter("naam1");  
    //Here I create an Object to compare everything with the input
    Compare checkOk = new Compare(JSON); //haal je ticketnummer op
    checkOk.haalIpAdress(request, response);
    checkOk.haalInputs(request, response);
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

    //This object is created to be able to add users to the IPTables
    IpTables ipTables = new IpTables(checkOk.getIpadress());

    //if TRUE the following commads are executed to 
    if (checkOk.vergelijkInput()) {
        try {
            ipTables.addIp();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RequestServlet.class.getName())
                    .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    response.sendRedirect("landingpage/agreementpage.html");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Tijd + naam , "Verbonden!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    } else {
        //ZAKA HIER MOET JE EEN NEW PAGE MAKEN MET ERROR
        response.sendRedirect("try_again.html");
    }
```

Comment: First of all, displaying pop-ups like this is a client-side activity, and you will need to write the appropriate Javascript code for this to happen.  Second of all, just from a user experience perspective, I would find such a pop-up rather annoying.

Comment: I agree its not the most user friendly way. But really that is not the point for this particular project. The fact that it is a client side activity makes total sense as well. Is there anyway to possibly inject the message into an existing html page header?